# ! Missing $ inserted.<inserted text>$ } in Latex but no _, ^, or other character used

Tags: latex

I'm getting an error, but looked at an old Stack Overflow, didn't quite answer my question because I have no `_` symbol in my code.

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amsfonts,graphicx}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\solution}[1]{\medskip\noindent{\color{cit}\textbf{Solution:}} #1}

\solution{
\begin{center}
P(A) = Getting into Northeastern\\*
P(B) = Getting into Boston University\\*
P(A \cap B) = Getting into both.\\*
(a)P(A) =0.5, P(B) =0.25, P(A \cap B) = 0.2, P(A choose B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} = 0.8 \\*
(b)P(A \cap B) = P(A) \times P(B) , and since 0.5 \times 0.25 \neq 0.2, \textbf{it is not independent}  \\*
(c)In reality, this tells us that getting into college is dependent on one another. So it will affect my odds for other colleges. \\*
\end{center}
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `center` environment is for text, not for mathmode. So, when you attempt to use a math command (such as `\cap` or `\frac`) outside of mathmode, LaTeX will try to correct for it by entering mathmode when it sees that command, and let you know about it via the `missing $ inserted` error message. If you want to use math commands properly in a text environment, you need to use inline mathmode by surrounding said command with `\(<command>\)` or `$<command>$`. For example, `P(A $\cap$ B) = \text{Getting into both.}\\` . Also, I am not sure what the asterisk in `\\*` is for but I don't believe that's necessary for a `center` environment.

Lastly, if you are looking to write a list, you should look into using the `enumerate` environment instead.

In the future, there is also a [TeX Stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) community for LaTeX-related questions.

Comment: +1, thank you so much, haha i've been trying to add/remove stuff for an hour, thank you random physics undergraduate student! I'm also an undergrad, but just learning latex.